# Calculating minimal orientation for a 3D array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 3D numpy array where every element is either 0 or 1.  I'd like to rotate this 3D information such that the volume of the 3D array needed to store the resultant data is minimised.

My first idea is to find the pair of 1 values which are farthest apart and call the vector between them the "x" axis, then find the pair of points which have the farthest distance from each other once you've removed the component of their vector in the direction of the new "x" axis.

Any idea?

Comment: Could you post an example?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis

Comment: I'm on phone so I can't elaborate but you're reinventing what is called singular value decomposition (SVD) and it will indeed let you compress the data if it has such patterns. You'll have to search for it yourself or wait for someone else to explain it more in depth though.